# Hypothetical Memory Usage Monitoring Program

Tags: c++, c, memory, monitoring

Would it be at all possible (I don't care about practicality or usefulness) to write a C or C++ program that monitored memory usage in the following, very basic way?

---

Given that declaring a variable without assigning it a value results in it having the value of whatever is already at its memory location, one could create a large array (thousands or millions of elements) and leave all the values unassigned.  Then to see if any of these elements have been overwritten, we would simply need to repeatedly compare their current values to a previous value.

---

I highly doubt this would be as simple as I posited above.  Assuming my doubt is well-founded, wherein would the problem lie and, more importantly, would it be something we could circumvent with some creative or esoteric code?  I imagine that the problem would be attributable to something along the lines of the declared, uninitialized elements being not allowing other system processes to write to their memory address.  Please give me some pointers! (heehee)  Thanks.

Comment: [Pointers?](http://xkcd.com/138/)

Comment: If you're referring to my last sentence, it was a pun, with "pointers" meaning "tips or advice" :P

Comment: Are you talking about code instrumentation?

Comment: Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity / Hanlon's razor

Comment: @BenSandeen (You were supposed to click the link ;) )

Comment: hahahaha, lol I completely missed that, but that's great!

Comment: I'm confused, why did this question get downvoted?  Did I commit some sort of faux pas on Stack Overflow?  Sorry if I did, I haven't really done much on here yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your program is in C
Creating a large array is limited to the extent free memory is allowed and how the OS limits you.

So let's say you created a pretty large array (uninitialized).
Now that memory is given to your process(program you ran) and no other process can access it ! (It's OS role to avoid such things , basic requirements of Virtualization).

So as no other process can access its value won't be changed once its allocated to you.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to deallocate that memory (or whatever the term is for the process that removes the process's ownership) and still monitor it for any changes over time?

Comment: No.  Once you give the memory back to the OS you cannot access it.

Comment: You can allocate then note the values and then free that memory but the problem is when you will try to monitor the values (now that region is not allocated to you) you will get some error and your program most probably will terminate (Segmentation Fault) this is because by checking the values at those memory location you are trying to access the location which is not assigned to you and OS try to avoid any access to memory by a process which is not allocated to it.